# python float division does not work

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.x

I have a python code where I want float division for two elements from matrix. I tried float() and from **future** import division but none of them work. Here is my code.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def backsub(U, b):
    N = np.shape(U)[0] 
    x = b.copy()
    x[N - 1, 0] = x[N - 1, 0] / U[N-1, N-1]  #This keeps giving me integer results. No matter I do float(x[N - 1, 0]) or from __future__ import division
    print x[N - 1, 0]
    for i in range(N - 2, -1, -1): 
        for j in range(i + 1, N, 1):
            x[i, 0] = x[i, 0] - U[i, j] * x[j]
        x[i, 0] = x[i, 0] / U[i, i]
    return x

b = np.matrix('1; 2; 3')
U = np.matrix('6, 5, 1; 0, 1, 7; 0, 0, 2')
print backsub(U, b)
```

output:

```
1
[[ 4]
 [-5]
 [ 1]]
```

Comment: Are your matrices actually using `dtype=float`? If they're `dtype=int`, nothing you do to make a float before you assign to them will help.

Comment: You're getting matrices with integer dtype. Use floats instead of ints when you create them.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Can someone post your solution as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
x[i, 0] = float(x[i, 0]) / U[i, i]
```

Just try

```
b = np.matrix('1; 2; 3', dtype=float)
U = np.matrix('6, 5, 1; 0, 1, 7; 0, 0, 2', dtype=float)
```

or you can also try

```
b = np.matrix([[1], [2], [3], dtype=float)
U = np.matrix([[6, 5, 1], [0, 1, 7], [0, 0, 2]], dtype=float)
```

Hoping it helps you.

Comment: Still not work. :( The problem is that x[N - 1, 0] = x[N - 1, 0] / U[N-1, N-1] should be float. No idea how to fix it.

Comment: I have edited answer. Let me know, if it works or not.